# Remove <pre>...</pre> blocks with shell commands

Tags: html, regex, shell, perl

I'd like to change

```
Example 1 
<pre class="code">
bla bla 
</pre>
Example 2 
<pre>
bla bla 
</pre>
```

to just

```
Example 1 
Example 2
```

So I need non-greedy matching and a regex.  I'm pretty sure I can't use `sed` - what shell commands could I use?

Comment: Why can't you use `sed`? what about `grep -v`?

Comment: It's HTML; use an HTML parser, not line-oriented tools like `sed` and `grep`.

Comment: Yep, you're right - I was trying to take a shortcut and it wound up biting me. +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I need non-greedy matching an a regex.

Not really. Assuming the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags are always on a line by themselves, there are no comments or other HTML tags, and you don't need to worry about unescaping HTML entities, you could use e.g.

```
perl -ne 'print unless m{^\s*<pre\b} .. m{^\s*</pre>}'
```

But using a real HTML parser might be a better idea:

```
perl -MHTML::Parser -e 'HTML::Parser->new(ignore_elements => ["pre"], default_h => [sub { print @_ }, "text"])->parse_file(*STDIN)' < input.html
```

(Details depend on what exactly you want to happen with the rest of the document.)

Comment: After more testing, I realized I *was* better off with a parser - I was either missing things or removing too much trying to do it with the first command.  And your parser command was perfect - I just added `"code"` to the `ignore_elements` list.